# YouTube channel name change not reflected in search result

Tags: youtube

[image]

I just changed my YouTube channel’s name and if I visit the channel at its url, then I see the new name. In search, it still shows the old name and only comes up after searching for the old name. What do I do in this situation? How can I properly change my channel name? [image]

Answer (score 1):

It will take a while for your new channel name to be updated across all Google sergers. Give it some time and you’ll see your new channel name show up in search.

I changed my YouTube channel name as well and noticed it took a while to update site-wide.